# SVM formula variations

Tags: machine-learning, svm, notation

I was reading about SVM in Wikipedia and saw that the formula was written like this (with minus):

$$
\vec{w} \cdot \vec{x} - b = 0
$$

While other sources have it like this (with plus):

$$
\boldsymbol {w}^\text{T} \boldsymbol x + b = 0
$$

What are the differences in their meaning and which one should be used?
In essence I want to refer to the SVM formula and I don't know which one is the correct one.

Comment: Wikipedia is not an authoritative source. Personally, I'd use the second one, because that's the one I've seen in books, but it doesn't really matter, because the formulas are essentially identical.

Comment: What interpretation does the 'minus' give to it compared to the 'plus'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is more correct than the other, and you aren't going to get radically different interpretations from a sign change (as $b$ from one formulation can have the exact same interpretation as $-b$ in the other). Choices like this are usually made on the basis of what makes the formulas easier to write or look more aesthetically appealing, not interpretation.

Writing $w \cdot x - b = 0 \iff w \cdot x = b$ is (aesthetically) nice if you want to think of the hyperplane as a level curve of the function $f(x) = w \cdot x$ that corresponds to the value $b$. But you can just as easily interpret $w \cdot x + b = 0$ as the level curve corresponding to $-b$, so there is no difference in interpretation.

It's worth pointing out that Vapnik (one of the inventors of SVMs) uses $w \cdot x + b = 0$ in the *Theory of Statistical Learning*, so perhaps that's the "canonical" choice.